# Попытка работать с QscrollArea с помощью наполнения "мышкой"

Tags: c++, qt

В QscrollArea не работает ползунок что делать ???
scrollArea задал а прокрутка в нем не работает . Что я делаю не так ??? 
Хочу сделать это мышкой, ибо веся ui была набрана мишкой а не прописана кодом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: элементы внутри QScrollArea объединили одним layout?

Comment: а как ??? QGridLayout *l = new QGridLayout; вот такую строку создать могу а дальше у меня не выходит (не знаю что писать ) .

Comment: так кодом или мышкой?

Comment: @KoVadim  без разницы ))

Comment: Надо тыркнуть на scrollArea и сверху в окне прменить соответствующий лейаут. В вашем случае либо grid, либо form (третья или четвертая кнопки справа)

Comment: @Bearded Beaver понял вас но не могли бы поподробнее,  один раз вышло , а потом как то очеь плохохо пошло и не получалось изменить его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем спасибо @Bearded Beaver -у  за ответ , но я еще дополню что у меня вышло только когда я отказался от QWidget-а .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]